# How to appeal a down vote based on false allegation?

Tags: discussion, downvoting

[Did St. Thomas of Aquinas deny the Holy Spirit proceeds immediately from the Father alone?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/69055/did-st-thomas-of-aquinas-deny-the-holy-spirit-proceeds-immediately-from-the-fat)

In my recent post, I was downvoted by a user who accused me for confusing Gennadius II Scholarius who lived in the 15th century with Gennadius I Scholarius from the 5th century in regards to the former being a Byzantine Thomist. I can see an argument to sustain a downvote if the post is false or bad but as it is stand I fail to find a validation for a downvote on false allegation. I have updated in the footnote with a reference of the said appraisal on Aquinas by Gennadius II Scholarius. From the Help section a down vote is meant to signal that the post is not well written or contain false information. But as it's stand I believe my post is well researched. I wonder if an admin or other member can help me on this. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 10):

Up and down votes are anonymous, and unless someone tells you how they voted, it is both presumptuous and rude to accuse someone else of voting a certain way. You can't know *who* gave you that downvote, let alone why.

The reason why votes are anonymous is because of exactly what you're doing here: trying to gatekeep the voting process. It's not possible to objectively rank answers, and that's why voting is inherently subjective. The only kind of formally invalid downvote is a serial downvote, when someone repeatedly downvotes (or upvotes) one user's posts regardless of what the posts are.

If you want the downvote to be reversed, your best course of action is to edit your post to be as clear and well-written as possible. But there's no guarantee the original downvoter will see the revised post, or that even if they do they'll decide to reverse their vote. Remember, their reason for downvoting it may have nothing to do with whatever you changed in the edit.

By posting in Meta and drawing attention to your question, you may get results that are the opposite of what you wanted. Now your question will have more attention paid to it than it did before, and many people may think that you're acting like a sore loser and view your post more negatively as a result. That's unfortunate, and ideally wouldn't be a factor in how people vote, but it's reality. Take this as a learning opportunity.